# Display only the top n results from classifier.predict_proba(X)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, predict

Can I make sklearn's `classifier.predict_proba(X)` to display only the top n probabilities that are above m% instead of displaying the probabilities for each and every class? Is there an option/parameter that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no parameter to do that, but you can simply do an argsort:

```
np.argsort(classifier.predict_proba(X), axis=1)[-5:]
```